# How to create debian package with CPack command (not from CMake's files)?

Tags: linux, cmake, deb, cpack

I have CMake project built and installed.
Now I want to generate debian package (*.deb) from this. In the Internet there are many instructions how to create debian package with adding something to CMake's files, but the project, which I've built does not belongs to me, so I shouldn't modify its source.
I've found command `cpack`, which is can also generate deb packages. Unfortunately when I try to use the command:

```
cpack -G DEB -C cmake/build/directory -P myPackage.deb -R 1.0.
```

I see:

```
CPack Error: Please specify build tree of the project that uses CMake using CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS, specify CPACK_INSTALL_COMMANDS, CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT, or CPACK_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES.
```

Unfortunately the options can't be specified in commands in help:

```
cpack --help
```

So is it possible to generate debian package with command `cpack` without any changes to CMake files?

Comment: "So is it possible to generate debian package with command cpack without any changes to CMake files?" - Probably, yes, you could use CPack without CMake project. But you are right, that CPack commands are simply not described in the official documentation. The same is true for other CMake derivatives like CTest.

Comment: "but the project, which I've built does not belongs to me, so I shouldn't modify its source." - Unsure about legal issues, but there are ways for modify the project's files and still be able to synchronize them with the project's repo. E.g. you may create a patch and apply it when you want to pack the project. If you want to create CMake project which drives packaging of external project, you may use [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) command for that purpose. Its option `PATCH_COMMAND` may be used for applying the patch.

Answer (score 4):

When the `CMakeLists.txt` includes the `CPack` module, it produces `CPackConfig.cmake` in the top build directory. This config file is the default for CPack, but you can override it w/ `--config` option.

The file consists of a bunch of `set()` commands to set various [`CPACK_*` variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html). To produce a package (the DEB in your question) you ought to write the config file "manually" and set vital variables for CPack, as well as some for `DEB` generator (i.e. [`CPACK_DEBIAN_*`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html)).

Generally, this config (the variables in it) describes what project(s) and it's components to include to package(s), define some meta-data & so on... In theory, you can pass all that defines via `-D` options to `cpack(1)`. In practice, IMHO, it'll be easier to write the `CPackConfig.cmake` %)

Having that config file this command should to what you want:

```
$ cpack -G DEB
```

(or just `cpack` alone if your config describes only Debian package to build).